# Listener Virtual Keyboard every time and every where

Tags: android, keyboard, external, virtual

I have a personal keyboard connected to my Android Device, like I run Android in emulation in vmware and for search something in chrome I use keyboard of PC, it's the same.
We want to create a listernt / input method , something with that I can control the input from keyboard , not the keyboard of Android but connected with USB.
You have a idea ?
I want to create an app for shortcut from external keyboard, like if I push "aa " whatsapp come out.

Thanks